# Create own @Test annotation for JUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, annotations, junit4

For a set of JUnit 4.11 tests I have created an own annotation (let's call it `@MyTest`) which I am applying to some of the unit tests. As it stands I have to annotate those tests with both `@Test` and `@MyTest` - not the best solution I think. As inheritance is not possible with annotations I have tried building a custom runner but so far without success. Here's what that looks like so far:

```java
public class MyRunner extends Suite {

    public MyRunner(Class<?> klass, RunnerBuilder builder)
            throws InitializationError {
        super(klass, modifyBuilder(builder));
    }

    private static final RunnerBuilder modifyBuilder(RunnerBuilder builder) {
        if(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.class.isAssignableFrom(builder.getClass())) {    
            return new AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder(true) {
                @Override
                public Runner runnerForClass(Class<?> testClass)
                        throws Throwable {
                    List<RunnerBuilder> builders = Arrays.asList(
                            ignoredBuilder(),
                            annotatedBuilder(),
                            suiteMethodBuilder(),
                            junit3Builder(),
                            junit4Builder(),
                            myTestBuilder());

                    for (RunnerBuilder each : builders) {
                        Runner runner = each.safeRunnerForClass(testClass);
                        if (runner != null) {
                            return runner;
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                private RunnerBuilder myTestBuilder() {
                    return new RunnerBuilder() {

                        @Override
                        public MyAnnotationRunner runnerForClass(Class<?> testClass)
                                throws Throwable {
                            return new MyAnnotationRunner(testClass);
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        } else {
            return builder;
        }
    }
}
```

And the `MyAnnotationRunner` class:

```java
public class MyAnnotationRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public MyAnnotationRunner(Class<?> klass) throws InitializationError {
        super(klass);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {
        return getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(MyTest.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void validateTestMethods(List<Throwable> errors) {
        validatePublicVoidNoArgMethods(MyTest.class, false, errors);
    }
}
```

However so far when I run the tests it doesn't care about the `@MyTest` annotation; indeed if I comment out the line `junit4Builder(),` in the builders list it doesn't run any tests at all.

Am I going the wrong way or is this the correct idea but incomplete so far? (And I can't switch to TestNG or another testing framework, in case anyone wanted to suggest that.)

**Edit:**

The solution (as suggested by Bobbo) wasn't in the code posted above - that's all correct it seems. The `@MyTest` annotation however was missing the `@Retention` annotation; the correct definition should look like this:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyTest { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your MyTest annotation is set to be retained at Runtime using the Retention annotation, i.e.

```
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public @interface MyTest {}
```

Otherwise `computeTestMethods()` in `MyAnnotationRunner`  will be returning an empty list.

Also, if you want to run anything annotated with `@Test` as well, you'll need to change the method to something like the following:

```
protected List<FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {
    List<FrameworkMethod> methods = new ArrayList<>(); 
    methods.addAll(getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(Test.class));
    methods.addAll(getTestClass().getAnnotatedMethods(MyTest.class));
    return methods;
}
```

I haven't tested this using a Suite as you have though, I simply run the test class using the runner and it seems to work as you require:

```
@RunWith(MyAnnotationRunner.class)
public class Tests {
    @Test
    public void testUsingNormalTestAnnotation() {
        Assert.fail();
    }

    @MyTest
    public void testUsingMyTestAnnotation() {
        Assert.fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: Damn, the `@Retention` annotation... So simple yet that was the one thing I forgot. :-D Changing the `computeTestMethods()` is a good point too, I thought that having both the `JUnit4Builder` and my own Builder would do the job but apparantly not. Anyway, thanks! :-)